# How to drag and drop divs and place them adjacently in a horizontal line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using some javascript and jquery code to place divs in another div using drag and drop functionality. I want to place the div images Horizontally adjacent to one another and get their values. I have many divs and I m new to javascript and jquery stuff. Please help me in this regards. 
Following is the code :

```js
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

```html
<div id="11" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><img src="images/driver1.png" name="Driver"><span>Driver 1</span></div>
<div id="12" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><img src="images/driver1.png" Draggable="true" name="Driver"><span>Driver 2</span></div>
<div id="13" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><img src="images/driver1.png" Draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" name="Driver" id="13"><span>Driver 3</span></div>
<div id="14" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><img src="images/driver1.png" Draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" name="Driver" id="14"><span>Driver 4</span></div>
<div id="15" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"> <img src="images/driver1.png" Draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" name="Driver" id="15"><span>Driver 5</span> &nbsp</div>
```

How can I place the divs Horizontally?

Comment: You could add some CSS like `div { display: inline-block; }` to keep them horizontal. Still not sure if this would fix the issue as I can't see all of your HTML and CSS(if you have any). This is just a guess.

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. But my second part of the question is how to associate data from different divs and concatenate the result to show in a single list?

Comment: Okay awesome! If you could mark my Answer below as correct I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: As far as your secondary question goes, I'm not entirely sure what you mean? We could figure it out together, but it would be a secondary question not associated with the first. So I will need a bit of additional info on what specifically you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to give each child div a width.
2. Make sure the parent container has a set width.
3. You need to set the child divs to display:inline-block;

Once set, they should automatically align inline when you drop a new element.

If you cannot set implicit widths on the elements, then use Flexbox instead.

Comment: Please reply my second part of the question I would be very thankful to you.

Comment: I thought I did.This will align your divs horizontally. I reread your question, but I do not see a second part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Confirmed as working answer in OP's question comments above.

Add the following to your CSS:

```
div { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted when the OP confirmed this as the working answer in the comments under his question?

Answer (score 1):

1. give id to the blocks you want to inline
2. now in you css file create style for the element with the id you defined.

```css
.inline{
display : inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div class="inline">1st div</div>
<div class="inline">2nd div</div>
<div class="inline">3rd div</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You don't want to duplicate id's as id's are unique identifiers. These would be better as classes.